# SPSS: correlating two vectors

Tags: vector, syntax, spss

I have two vectors in my dataset Vs = s1 to s10 and Vt= t1 to t10.
They describe two pictures and I want to know for each case what the correlation is.
However there is no such a function Cor(Vs, Vt) because Vectors are apparently not usable in the standard functions. There is even no mean(Vs)!
I tried to write syntax but failed also because the problem of missing variables (implementing pairwise deletion seems complex).
Any hint is welcome.
Is it possible to ask a question that is only seen by SPSS experts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! The SPSS tag makes sure people interested in SPSS questions will be notified about your question.

Answer (score 0):

calculating the correlation in the present structure is probably feasible but would be pretty complex. I suggest restructuring the data, then all becomes easy:

The code assumes you have some line ID in the data, called `lineNum`.
If you don't, you'll need to create one using the first line.

```
compute lineNum=$casenum. /* this is only necessary if you don't have some other line ID.
varstocases /mame V_s from S1 to S10 /make V_t from V1 to V10 /index=pairNum(V_s).
sort cases by lineNum. 
split file by lineNum. 
correlations V_s with V_t. /* you can edit the code here to add features to the analysis.
split file off.
```

That's it. Now the results will appear in the output window - one correlation for each of the original lines. If you need to import the correlations back to the original data you can do that by using `OMS` control to capture the results into a new dataset and then matching it back to the original file.